# How to convert various date formats in character to date format in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table that has a character data type column which has varying date formats.

```
01/02/2022
 1/2/2022
9/11/2022
10/2/2022
 9/5/2022 12:00:00 AM
```

When to_date(created_date,'mm/dd/yyyy') is used, it fails with ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string.

When to_date(created_date,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss PM') is used, the select statement returns without any issue. However, when I try to Insert into a table, then ORA-01858:a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected occurs.

Sample code I have used:

```
CASE 
   WHEN instr(created_date,' ' = 0) 
   THEN to_date(created_date,'mm/dd/yyyy')
   WHEN instr(created_date,' ' > 0) 
   THEN to_date(substr(created_date,1,instr(created_date,' ')),'mm/dd/yyyy')
END formatted_date
```

This works when run as a SELECT but when used in conjunction with INSERT is causing ORA-01858 error.

Appreciate your help !!

Comment: _when used in conjunction with INSERT_ Can you [edit] your question and post that INSERT statement?

Comment: If you know all the variations upfront, you may use `coalesce` and `to_date(... default null on conversion error )` providing different formats. See [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118). To avoid unexpected nulls the last `to_date` should be used without `default ... on conversion error`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` function to check what rows have valid dates in the format you want. However, if you only have the formats that are in your examples then the format mask `'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'` should do:

```
WITH
dates  AS (
SELECT '01/02/2022' dates_col FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '1/2/2022' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '9/11/2022' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '10/2/2022' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '9/5/2022 12:00:00 AM' FROM dual 
) SELECT 
  VALIDATE_CONVERSION(dates_col AS DATE,
    'DD/MM/YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'), 
  VALIDATE_CONVERSION(dates_col AS DATE,
    'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')       
    FROM dates;

1   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
0   1
```